# use module global scope to define private class fields accessible from prototype

Tags: javascript

If a constructor and it's prototype are defined in the same module, say AMD module, is it acceptable to make class private fields global for the module to be accessible within prototype instead of defining them with underscore inside a constructor?

So is this better:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var steps = 0;

    function Constructor(_steps) {
        steps = _steps;
    }

    Constructor.prototype.go = function () {
        steps += 1;
    };
```

then this:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    function Constructor(_steps) {
        this._steps = _steps;
    }

    Constructor.prototype.go = function () {
        this._steps += 1;
    };
```

?

Comment: The 2 solutions are different. You cannot compare them since they behave differently.

Comment: Perhaps in latter you meant `Constructor.prototype._ = {}; function Constructor(_steps) {
        this._.steps = _steps;
    }`?

Comment: @zerkms however if `Constructor` is verified to be a singleton (which is the case with AMD module) the only difference is private/public access

Comment: @KirillSlatin, no, what's this pattern?

Comment: @zerkms, the goal is to have a class with private fields, how are they different in this sense?

Comment: @Maximus do you create multiple instances of the class? If so, do they share the same `steps` variable value?

Comment: @zerkms, ah, yeah, thanks, I forgot to tell it's a singleton

Comment: @Maximus then the second implementation does not have a "private" variable, since it's accessible outside

Comment: @zerkms, yes, it is accessible, but the convention is to not call variables with underscores on instances and there are tools that check it. AFAIK, there is no way to achieve private fields using prototype as opposed to accesing them through closure if defined inside a constructor.

Comment: So if it's a conventional based limitation - what is the purpose of the question? You ask "if it's acceptable" --- so cannot you answer if it's acceptable for you/your team according the convention you all accepted?

Comment: If it's a singleton, then there's no reason to use a constructor.

Comment: @zerkms, the purpose of every question is to learn something new. Event with this one, I've got some useful comments to pick new knowledge from. Thanks

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, can you point me to some resource showing the implementation you have in mind for the singletons?

Comment: @Maximus but it does not have the formal requirements. Everything that is based on conventions - is based on conventions. You may get some useful comments/answers, but they do not directly address what you asked, since it's only you who can answer it.

Comment: @zerkms, right, but it's just in comments that we get to conventions, at first it didn't seem to be about conventions to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR: doesn't really matter (it's just a minor implementation detail)

Two different solutions. One isn't necessarily "better" than the other, they just have different use cases.

If you're using the constructor/prototype pattern, then it makes sense in an object-oriented sense to set the constructor parameters *on the instance itself* (using `this.<whatever-prop>`). When you instead decide to use the constructor only for the sake of its *side effects* (by setting `someModuleVariable` based on the parameter passed to the constructor), it can unnecessarily obfuscate the code.

Having a "private" variable that's accessible to the entire module, however, is an extremely common pattern... For example, when using singleton objects, because scoped variables are never destroyed when you leave the execution context of the function, the module can still query that "module-local" variable.

The only thing that rubs me the wrong way is using the constructor only for the sake of its side effects... why would I use a constructor then, when one of the main purposes of a constructor is the implicitly set properties on the instance?

To separate these two ideas, a common pattern is to use an `init` method inside of the prototype, because *that's* a good place to harbor all of your desired side effects. For example, one could suggest doing this:

```
var Module = (function() {
  var somethingPrivate;

  function SomeObject(someProp) {
    // rely on the constructor to set instance properties
    this.someProp = someProp;
  }

  SomeObject.prototype = {
    init: function(_somethingPrivate) {
      // all of your side effects in here, such as:
      somethingPrivate = _somethingPrivate;
    }
  };

  return SomeObject;
}());

var module = new Module('Hello world! I belong to the instance');

module.init('I am a module-specific variable!');
```

Of course, however, this isn't saying that there aren't circumstances where you might want to rely on a constructor for its side effects. But in the example you gave, it doesn't even look like a constructor is necessary (even though I understand the example is contrived just for the sake of demonstrating the problem).

Where and how you use `_` underscores are mostly irrelevant, just as a side note. They're good in some cases, like to differentiate pseudo-private properties from "public" properties, but I think that's more of a convention than a pattern that's been set in stone.